# Manual file import of data to CDP

Tags: salesforce-cdp, cdp

Does anyone found a way of importing data to CDP manually from a file? Only way I discovered in Documentation close to this one is Cloud storage but maybe someone found another way.

Thanks for answers in advance .

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, it isn't possible to import file data directly via the UI as of now, but you can do it programmatically leveraging the Customer Data Platform Bulk Ingestion API: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.c360a_api.meta/c360a_api/c360a_api_bulk_ingestion.htm?q=csv